# Cannot block the form submission with Ajax response fired by onSubmit attribute.

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, forms, onsubmit

This question is a bit different from the ones already answered...

What I'm looking to do is run a function, `autoHide()`, that calls a PHP file, `artistdo.php`, that executes a MySQL query, on form submit and if it returns true (the query succeeds), the form doesn't submit.

What I'm getting is that the MySQL query isn't running and even if I remove the query and place return true in the `artistdo.php` page, the return false in the ajax doesn't stop the form submission but it does cause the `alert("Success");` to be called, however, if I put return false within the `autoHide()` function but outside the AJAX, the form correctly doesn't submit. Here's what I have so far:

The form page:

```
<head>
    function autoHide() {
        $.ajax({
            'url': '/artistdo.php',
            'type': 'GET',
            'dataType': 'json',
            'data': {
                cmd: 'autoHideProduct'
            },
            'success': function () {
                alert("Success");
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
</head>

<body>
  <form action="http://off-site/form.php" method="post" 
        onSubmit="return autoHide()">
    <input type="submit" value="submit"
           onMouseOver="this.style.cursor='pointer'">
  </form>
```

And the `artistdo.php` page (This is a simplified version for the sake of easy reading) :

```
if($get['cmd'] == 'autoHideProduct') {
    $query = mysql_query("UPDATE products SET house='0'");

    if ($query) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
```

So, if I completely remove the entire MySQL query from the `artistdo.php` page and replace it with nothing but `return true;`, the form still submits, which makes me think the problem is in the AJAX since, the `artistdo.php` page is definitely returning true and the `alert("Success");` is being called. 
If I move the `return true` to outside the AJAX call, the form correctly doesn't submit.

I hope this makes sense...

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) method to associate metadata with the form that will allow you to know whether you should submit it or not:

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $('#myform').submit(function() {
                if ($(this).data('shouldSubmit')) {
                    return true;
                }

                $.ajax({
                    url: '/artistdo.php',
                    type: 'GET',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    context: this,
                    data: { cmd: 'autoHideProduct' },
                    success: function (result) {
                        if (result) {
                            $(this)
                                .data('shouldSubmit', true)
                                .submit();
                        }
                    }
                });

                return false;
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <form action="http://off-site/form.php" method="post" id="myform">
        <!-- Form fields -->
        <input type="submit" value="submit" onMouseOver="this.style.cursor='pointer'">
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the response!  I had to remove the 'result' part of the success but it works perfectly! Thanks again. I'd vote up but I'm new and don't have the rep yet.

Answer (score 0):

if I understood you correctly, this may be of some help

```
$('form').submit(function (event)
{
    event.preventDefault();
    //handle the rest of the logic
}
```

This will stop the form submission, u should call your function and submit the form if the return is true.

Comment: I tried using this and it would've worked but I had a problem with the function continually repeating itself when I tried submitting the form through the javascript which was fixed by adding some code from Darin Dimitrov reply below.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The first problem given your current code structure is that the call to `$.ajax` is asynchronous which means that it gets executed and then the browser moves on to the next statement and lets the `$.ajax` call finish "in the background".  This is why when you put the `return false` statement after the `$.ajax` call the form doesn't submit as opposed to putting the return false inside the success function of the `$.ajax` call.

I don't think what you want to do is really possible unless you create a global variables of some kind.  Is it possible for you to change how you are doing the form?

Comment: This would be the easiest and most direct way of taking care of the problem but I can make work-arounds.  Thanks for your reply!

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in this line

```
    if($get['cmd'] == 'autoHideProduct') {
```

it should be like

```
    if($_GET['cmd'] == 'autoHideProduct') {
```

Comment: I apologize I didn't mention I have:
`foreach($_GET as $key => $value) {
 $get[$key] = filter($value);
}`
at the top of my artistdo.php page so `$get` is correct.  Thanks for the reply.